# Is the kernel of this group action the centralizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

In Dummit and Foote, they state

"... let the group $N_G(A)$ (normalizer) act on the set $A$ by conjugation.  It is easy to check that the kernel of this action is the centralizer $C_G(A)$."

From what I understand, the kernel of this action is the set
$$ \{ g \in N_G(A) : g a g^{-1} = a \text{ for all } a \in A \}. $$
However, the centralizer of $A$ is
$$ \{ g \in G : g a g^{-1} = a \text{ for all } a \in A \}. $$
If this is true, I see that the kernel is a *subset* of the centralizer, but how are they equal?

Comment: The centraliser is always contained in the normaliser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We always have $C_G(A) \subset N_G(A)$, since

$$N_G(A) = \{g\in G : gAg^{-1} = A\} = \left\{ g \in G : \bigl(\forall a \in A\bigr)\bigl(gag^{-1}\in A\bigr)\right\},$$

and of course a group element that fixes $A$ elementwise under conjugation fixes $A$ as a set.

So the kernel of the group action is

$$N_G(A) \cap C_G(A) = C_G(A).$$